# How to convert a string into json format in flink side?

Tags: json, apache-flink

I received a one digit as string format, for example, which look like `12`.
What I want to do is to convert those strings into a json format and
write them to the text file in my local directory.

However, I didn't get the right solution except for those things that manually change the strings so that it looks like the json format. I think it is tedious and laborious tasks.

The completed json format will be shown as below.

`{"temperature": 12}`

Is there any libraries that achieve my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). In particular, if you have a Java class with a single "temperature" field, then [see this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples) for how to convert to Json.